# How to get by "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store." loop

Tags: app-store, apple-id

So I just got an iMac, and I am trying to use the App Store. I downloaded an app, and then it says "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store." So I click "Review" and enter my login info, but it shows me the same message and no matter how many times I put in my password, it does this forever.

How can I bypass this message?